# Can SQL queries be used in REST api (c#) in Visual Studio to post data to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

My api's Post method is as follows, but I want to send date using `DateTime.now` and also want to update a Sequence value used in my database using `NextValueFor()` but Post can only send json data and not any SQL queries to my database. How should I do it?

Also my database `ICT`, table `AddNewRequest`, and model class:

```
public partial class AddNewRequest 
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string SubCateory { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ScreenshotPath { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RequestId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> EngineerId { get; set; }
    public string RequestStatus { get; set; }
}

public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]AddNewRequest newRequest)
{
    try
    {
        using (ICTEntities entities = new ICTEntities())
        {
            entities.AddNewRequests.Add(newRequest);
            entities.SaveChanges();

            var message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, newRequest);
            message.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri +"/"+ newRequest.Id.ToString());

            return message;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your code and add more details

Comment: `but I want to send date using DateTime.now` Do you want that to be the server's datetime or the caller's datetime?

Comment: What do you mean by "Post can only send json data and not any SQL queries to my database"? You can do whatever you want in the method, including make database calls, so I don't understand your question.

Comment: i want to add the server's time

Comment: @CraigW. I dont know how to implement queries in post ..Please help

Comment: You're already doing it. The code that creates the `ICTEntities`, adds a new object to the collection and calls `SaveChanges` is sending a query to the database (i.e. an `INSERT` statement).

Comment: Okk, Thanks .How should I modify that particular Insert Statement? Is it a gud practice to modify it or not?